# How to parse warc data for robots.txt info

Tags: python, warc

I have the following code that I am writing to get values from a warc file. My goal is to find sites that have:

```
User-Agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

I would like it to only print URLs that have the above robots.txt rules ^

My Python code that currently only prints one line that is the URL:

```
file = 'robots.warc'
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(file, errors='ignore'))
print('file has', num_lines , 'lines')

with open(file, errors='ignore') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("WARC-Target-URI:"):
            print(line)
```

Here is an [example warc file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tcope25/5354d05236bba026042bd8e6df1845fa/raw/f9e3445c7414ded101461fbe309678d08570b8b9/gistfile1.txt)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python has a built-in [robotparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.robotparser.html) library that may be helpful (I've never used it).

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks. that looks more like it calls the url. my file already has the robots.txt data, I just need to parse through it

Comment: Regular expressions then?